# Android Qualifiers Not Working for the Notion Ink Adam

Tags: layout, android, screens, qualifiers

I'm making an app and I'm nearing completion, now I'm trying to optimize it for different screen sizes and pixel densities.  One of the devices (using an emulator) is really frustrating me.  I can't seem to find a qualifier that edits the Notion Ink Adam (1024x800 or something, 10.1 inches).  According to this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html , Notion Ink Adam at 10.1 inches should be considered "xlarge" in a qualifier.  However, when I use this in my qualifier like "layout-xlarge" the Notion Ink Adam emulator doesn't follow it.

I also tried using "layout-xlarge-hdpi" because I have another folder that's "layout-hdpi" that the Notion Ink Adam follows, but I'm using THAT qualifier for other devices.  Also I've tried "layout-hdpi-long" but it also edits my other "long" hdpi devices.  Notion Ink Adam is a tablet, and I'm just trying to seperate: 1) tablets like the Notion Ink Adam, 2)MDPI screens, the smaller screens, and 3) Long hdpi screens like the Nexus One and Motorola Droid.

My main problem is trying to find a qualifier that seperates 1 and 3, the tablet always follows my qualifier for the long hdpi screens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for xlarge devices was introduced only in Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) and later.  If your Adam is still running Froyo, it will report itself as "large" and will not find xlarge resources.

I developed an app, "ScreenInfo", which will cause an Android device to report its screen size and density classification.  You can [find it in the Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo&feature=search_result), or [grab the source](https://github.com/mportuesisf/ScreenInfo).

To help you sort out the various categories:

- small-screened phones (like the original G1): normal-mdpi
- most high-end smartphones w/3.7-4.5 inch screens: normal-hdpi
- small-screened tablets (7-inch): large-mdpi, or in the case of the Galaxy Tab 7, large-hdpi
- large-screened tablets (10-inch): xlarge-mdpi

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you're already doing everything correctly - using `-xlarge` for tablets, `-hdpi`, `-mdpi`, and so on for the appropriate screen densities, and so on.  If the Adam's emulator (or the actual device) don't pull from the `-xlarge` layout already, it's probably in your best interest to simply ignore it.  It's not a particularly popular tablet now that the Android 3.x devices are out (probably wasn't even before that, but I don't know), and if they're ignoring standards, all the more reason to ignore them in favor of what works for the majority of devices.

In terms of common qualifiers, I'm not sure what you mean, but if you go by the information in the documentation you linked, that's what's "common."

Answer (score 0):

Adam reports itself as a large device. So, xlarge resources wont work on Adam.